# JavaScript Function Not Defined - jQuery Words Rotator Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page, with the set up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/css/jquery.wordrotator.min.css">
            <script src="themes/js/jquery.wordrotator.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/css/animate.css">

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#myWords").wordsrotator({
                    words: ['Maths', 'English']
                });
            });
            </script>
```

The wordsrotator is the code as specified here:
https://github.com/andreapace/wordsrotator/blob/master/jquery.wordrotator.min.js

And built using the example here:
http://www.andreapace.co.uk/wordsrotator/installation.html

However, the error I seem to constantly have is:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Picking up on the Line:

```
$("#myWords").wordsrotator({
```

I have tried swapping the order that things are loaded, I have tried various input (e.g. not just 'Maths and English), I have even copy and pasted the code exactly as it is, with no joy.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Your browser's developer console should be telling you which JS files are failing to load.

Comment: @Pointy No files are failing to load. Chrome is showing the JavaScript file (currently) as 304 Not Modified.

Comment: Well make sure in the console that `$` and `$.fn.wordsrotator` are defined. The code [seems to work in this CodePen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/ByRojm)

Comment: How would I go about checking them in the console?

Comment: Just type `$` at the "Console" prompt and hit enter; the console should tell you it's a function (you can try it right here on the Stackoverflow page). Then type `$.fn.wordsrotator` and hit enter. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work if the libraries are really loading and your code looks just like what you posted.

Comment: @Pointy I've just tried what you suggested, and it returns undefined. I've also seen the text `alert(jQuery.jquery);` which I believe returns the version number. However, this also returns undefined. jQuery is definitely being loaded from [link](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js) as it's shown in the network tab - it's the second thing loaded after the page itself

Comment: If jQuery were really being loaded and your code looks like what you posted, then `$` would be defined. I can't see your console so I'm not sure what to tell you, but the code works (as can be seen in the CodePen I linked) when the libraries load.

Comment: It's really odd, and the reason why it's stumped me. The library is loaded (as shown in the network tab), the code loads in the correct order, and the code is correct (copied from example). Thanks for helping anyway @Pointy - appreciate it!

Comment: Only additional thing I can think of is to look for a *subsequent* JS library import that calls `jQuery.noConflict()` - if `$` is `undefined` but there's a global `jQuery` (or some other tell-tale name), then that might be what's happening to you.